# Resharper's redundant 'Remove code redundancies' settings

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-9.0

Just noticed this in Resharper's (9.2) Code Cleanup settings page:

[image: Settings page showing 'Remove code redundancies' option twice]

Are these settings different in anyway?  Or are the Resharper devs just messing with us?

Comment: This also appears in 10.0.2, although the two duplicate settings are right next to each other, making it even more obvious.

Comment: I like this setting.  Especially showing it to others with the comment "What about this looks wrong" and just watching their face as they find it.  But it always brings up the question:  What if we set them differently from one another?  Does a hole open up in the universe?

Comment: You should have posted this twice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-437296) is expected to emerge soon:

> Fixed In Version ReSharper
>
> 10.1 EAP 4